# Finding only numbers at the beginning of a filename with regex

Tags: regex, bash

I'm (a regex noob) trying to find only the files in a directory that begin with numbers and not strings.

My regex is

```
 .*/^\d+\w+[A][D][0-5][0-9].mat
```

(The end of the file name has the letters AD and then numbers from 0-54 before the MAT extension. I include `./` because I am going to pass this to `find` in `bash`.)

However, this returns false for both files like

```
./times_121312_going_down_AD33.mat
```

and

```
./121312_going_down_AD33.mat
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect ^ in your expression to do?  Outside of [] it matches the  null  string  at  the beginning of a line, and after you match `.*/` the ^ cannot match.

Comment: Oh, I thought it signaled that the expression following it should match the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a working example with [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

```
$ ls -l *.mat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 13 15:09 121312_going_down_AD33.mat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 13 15:09 times_121312_going_down_AD33.mat

$ find . -type f -regex '.*/[0-9]+_.*AD[0-5][0-9]\.mat$'
./121312_going_down_AD33.mat
```

`\d` and `\w` don't work in [POSIX regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX), you could use `[:digit:]` tho

The regular expression explained

- `.*` repeat any character except\n, zero or more times
- `/` match character '/' literally
- `[0-9]+` repeat any char in 0 to 9, one or more times
- `_` match character '_' literally
- `.*` repeat any character except\n, zero or more times
- `A` match character 'A' literally
- `D` match character 'D' literally
- `[0-5]` Match any char in 0 to 5
- `[0-9]` Match any char in 0 to 9
- `\.` match '.' literally
- `m` match 'm' literally
- `a` match 'a' literally
- `t` match 't' literally
- `$` end of string

If you just want to match all files beginning with an integer you can break it down to `.*/[0-9]` which would also match `./12/test.tmp` and `./12_not_a_mat_file.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that neither `\d` nor `\w` work in POSIX regular expressions. Because I'm passing this command to MATLAB running on a cluster, this is important.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp: `.*/\d+\w+[A][D][0-5][0-9]\.mat` (there shouldn't be `^` and you have to remember to escape a dot `.` because without `\` it simply means "any character".

You can always try this assuming that you `[A][D][0-5][0-9]` part was not important: `.*/\d\w+\.mat`

Answer (score 1):

The `\d` etc notation you're using is from perl (and maybe other places too), but not supported by the `bash` command line.

You'll need to use

```
 ./[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*
```

To match a 5 digit + "anything else" value.

If need to match for 1-n possible digits at the front, you'll need to "OR" together those possibilities. A case statement can help sort that out and make it a little more managable, i.e.

```
 case ${fileName} in
  ./[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*|./[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*) echo "4 or 5 nums at front" ;;
  ./[0-9]*|./[0-9][0-9]*|./[0-9][0-9][0-9]* ) echo "up to 3 nums at front" ;;
  #-------^-------------^--- note the '|' regex OR
 esac
```

Note that you have to test for the longer matches first, as the shorter match will also match the longer strings.

There are  other solutions depending on your needs, but this will not require starting a subprocess, so it's pretty efficient.

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a new enough bash, you can express what you are looking for using an exglob.

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in ./+([0-9])*AD[0-5][0-9].mat; do
    # do something with "$f"
done
```

Note, the above is not a recursive search, for bash-only recursive search, you'll need a version of bash which also supports globstar:

```
shopt -s extglob globstar
for f in ./**/+([0-9])*AD[0-5][0-9].mat; do
    # do something with "$f"
done
```

Alternatively, a recursive search can be done with GNU find's `-regex` option.