# How to match digits in regex in bash script

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to match some lines against regex that contains digits.

Bash version 3.2.25:

```
#!/bin/bash

s="AAA (bbb 123) CCC"
regex="AAA \(bbb \d+\) CCC"
if [[ $s =~ $regex ]]; then
  echo $s matches $regex
else
  echo $s doesnt match $regex
fi
```

Result:

```
AAA (bbb 123) CCC doesnt match AAA \(bbb \d+\) CCC
```

If I put `regex="AAA \(bbb .+\) CCC"` it works but it doesn't meet my requirement to match digits only.

Why doesn't `\d+` match `123`?

Comment: \d is not valid in an extended regex.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Either use standard character set or POSIX-compliant notation:

```
[0-9]    
[[:digit:]]
```

---

As read in [Finding only numbers at the beginning of a filename with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14304887/1983854):

> `\d` and `\w` don't work in [POSIX regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX), you could use `[:digit:]` though

so your expression should be one of these:

```
regex="AAA \(bbb [0-9]+\) CCC"
#                ^^^^^^
regex="AAA \(bbb [[:digit:]]+\) CCC"
#                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

All together, your script can be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

s="AAA (bbb 123) CCC"
regex="AAA \(bbb [[:digit:]]+\) CCC"
if [[ $s =~ $regex ]]; then
  echo "$s matches $regex"
else
  echo "$s doesn't match $regex"
fi
```

Let's run it:

```
$ ./digits.sh
AAA (bbb 123) CCC matches AAA \(bbb [[:digit:]]+\) CCC
```

Answer (score 19):

Digit notation `\d` doesn't work with your bash version. Use `[0-9]` instead:

```
regex="AAA \(bbb [0-9]+\) CCC"
```

Comment: At least with bash 4.3.11 (the one that comes with Ubuntu 14.04) `[0-9]+` doesn't work either, but `[0-9]*` does. Maybe `+` is unsupported?

Comment: `[0-9]+` worked for me on older BASH 3.2 as well so not sure why Ubuntu BASH is not liking it.

Comment: Hmmm, never mind, I got confused: it's `grep` that doesn't handle `+` (at least not without additional options). I got confused because my script both uses bash regex matching *and* grep.

Comment: oh `grep` by default uses `BRE` so `+` needs to be escaped. Otherwise you can use `grep -E` to support extended regex like above.

Comment: Yup, so I found out. Thanks!

Comment: Should `[0-9]{1,3}` for 1 to three digit numbers work?