# How to find a number in text at specific location using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

How to create a method which will find a number in String Text. I contain List of Strings which contain text like:

```
Radius of Circle is 7 cm
Rectangle 8 Height is 10 cm
Rectangle Width is 100 cm, Some text
```

Now I have to find all the number in these lines which are coming before cm so that I don't mistakenly find any other number.

How can it happen

Comment: You can do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014284/regex-to-match-2-digits-optional-decimal-two-digits, your gonna need to do a little more research. Your looking to match /\d\d cm/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to match digits in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968020/how-to-match-digits-in-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matching regular expression would be:

```
(\d+) cm
```

In order to obtain the captured number before the `cm`, you can use the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes:

```
String line = "Radius of Circle is 7 cm";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) cm");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Value: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

This example only matches the line from example (1), but can be easily repeated for each the lines contained in your list. See [Java Regex Capture Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969620/2403253) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find groups with only digits in the string using the following regex:

```
(?:\d{1,})
```

- \d{1,} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
- {1,} Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
- (?:) The capturing group

### Main##:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;  
import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.util.regex.Matcher;    
public class RegexExample{    
    public static void main(String[] args){    
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  
        while (true) {    
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d{1,})");    
            System.out.println("Enter text:");  
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sc.nextLine());    
            boolean found = false;    
            while (matcher.find()) {    
                System.out.println("I found the text "+matcher.group()+" starting at index "+    
                 matcher.start()+" and ending at index "+matcher.end());    
                found = true;    
            }    
            if(!found){    
                System.out.println("No match found.");    
            }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

### Example:

```
Enter text:
Radius of Circle is 7 cm
I found the text 7 starting at index 20 and ending at index 21
Enter text:
Rectangle 8 Height is 10 cm
I found the text 8 starting at index 10 and ending at index 11
I found the text 10 starting at index 22 and ending at index 24
Enter text:
Rectangle Width is 100 cm, Some text
I found the text 100 starting at index 19 and ending at index 22
Enter text:
```

Note: In java code, the character `\` it's an escape character. That's why you have to append another `\`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct pattern to use here is:

```
(\\d+)\\s+cm\\b
```

For a one liner, we can try using `String#replaceAll`:

```
String input = "Rectangle Width is 100 cm, Some text";
String output = input.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+)\\s+cm\\b.*", "$1");
System.out.println(output);
```

Or, to find all matches in a given text, we can try using a formal pattern matcher:

```
String input = "Rectangle Width is 100 cm, Some text";
String pattern = "(\\d+)\\s+cm\\b";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found measurement: " + m.group(1));
}
```