# regex101 vs SED

Tags: bash, sed

I am quite new in Linux SED, and I need to translate eg. below string:

```
5069 ;08 Aug 00:00;0
```

to

```
5069 ;08 Aug 2019 00:00:00;0
```

using SED.

I tested regrex on regex101.com webpage, but in SED it seems not to work correctly (I have used -r, --regexp-extended option).

reqular expression:

```
(\s.*\d.*\s;)(\d\d)\s(Aug)\s(\d\d:\d\d)(;\d)
```

substitution:

```
\1\2 \3 2019 \4:00\5
```

result on webpage (OK)

```
 5069 ;08 Aug 2019 00:00:00;0
```

But in bash is NOK.

```
echo "   5069 ;08 Aug 00:00;0" | sed -r 's/(\s.*\d.*\s;)(\d\d)\s(Aug)\s(\d\d:\d\d)(;\d)/\1\2 \3 2019 \4:00\5/g'
```

5069 ;08 Aug 00:00;0

What I am doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have to read about BRE(Basic Regular Expression) and ERE(Extended Regular Expression) to know what is possible with these kind of regex.

Comment: I tried your regex and substitution here and regex101.com says it is wrong https://regex101.com/r/7baGYd/2 So what exactly is the regex you tested ok into regex101.com ? Can you share the saved link as I did just here?

Comment: @grzegorz9922 : You can't use \d and \s in _sed_. See the _sed_ man-page, the section about _REGULAR EXPRESSIONS_, and the -E option of _sed_.

Comment: FYI see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info) for more help on sed and in particular [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) for character classes and the following paragraph for regular expression extensions.

Comment: @Léa Gris - please add space at the beginning - when is correct.

Comment: What space when is correct?. I don't understand. What I asked is what is the RegEx you validated with Regex101, because the one you published here is not matching anything at all.

Comment: Please check below link https://regex101.com/r/7baGYd/3

Comment: Now updated to `sed` compatible RegEx https://regex101.com/r/7baGYd/4

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is your friend, your translation can be handled by:

```
awk '{$3=$3" 2019"; $4="00:"$4}1'
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "5069 ;08 Aug 00:00;0" | awk '{$3=$3" 2019"; $4="00:"$4}1'
5069 ;08 Aug 2019 00:00:00;0
```

**Explanation**

`awk` allows you to operate on the *fields* present in each line of input (default: space delimited). `awk` starts counting fields at `1`. So above the string to be modified is *piped* to `awk` on `stdin` and then `awk` can modify the input with the following rule (what is between `{...}`):

- `$3=$3" 2019"` - uses string concatenation to add `" 2019"` to the 3rd field;
- `$4="00:"$4` - prepends `"00:"` to the beginning for the 4th field; and
- `1` at the end after the rule is shorthand for print the record.

Resulting in your desired string.

Note: you can have as many rules as you like that will be applied in the order listed.

Comment: You are welcome. Both `sed` and `awk` play dual-roles in text processing. While `awk` has advantages if you need to handle differing multi-line changes, it can also provided advantages if you look at your problem from an individual *field* within a line standpoint as well. In cases where you need to act on different fields, `awk` provides for `field` separation that can greatly simplify a regex designed to handle all fields at once. In other cases, `sed` provides a better solution. Learning both isn't quick, but well worth the time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
$ echo " 5069 ;08 Aug 00:00;0" | sed -r 's/;([0-9]{2} [A-Z][a-z]{2}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2});/;\1 2019 \2;/g'
 5069 ;08 Aug 2019 00:00;0
```

The reason why `\d` is not match was answered in [how to match digits in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968020/how-to-match-digits-in-regex):

> `\d` and `\w` don't work in POSIX regular expressions, you could use `[:digit:]` though