# Pandas string regex problem to extract muliple digit numbers

Tags: python, regex, pandas

In the following problem how to extract only the number using regex?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['< 1 year','1 year', '2 year', '10+ years',np.nan]})
df
```

## My attempt

```py
df['A'].str.replace('< 1 year', '0').str.extract(r'.*(\d+).*')
```

I am getting `0` for `10` years. How to get the correct answer.

NOTE: I am looking for regex method, of course, I can easily do using multiple `str.replace` methods.

Comment: try this : df.A.str.extract(r'(\d+)')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match digits in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968020/how-to-match-digits-in-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put a '\d+' for regex?
That whould give the correct answer and

extract all the numbers for an item in a list

And as sammywemmy said try it like that:

```
df.A.str.extract(r'(\d+)')
```

Comment: Why the capture group?